# Auto message timer in discord with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, discord

Im trying to have my program send a message in a chat every 15 minutes, but once I log into the discord, I can't get selenium to work. How can I select a server and chat then type on it. Or I could manually select the server and chat, but then how could the program type in it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Brandon\PycharmProjects\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://discordapp.com/channels/@me')
time.sleep(2)

email = browser.find_element_by_name('email')
email.send_keys('email123')
time.sleep(1)

password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('password123')
time.sleep(2)

verify = browser.find_element_by_class_name("contents-18-Yxp").click() #log in button but there is a verification I need to manually click then log in again
time.sleep(10)

verify.find_element_by_class_name("wrapper-2B2Wx1").click() #supposed to select server, but doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
browser.get('https://discordapp.com/channels/SERVER ID/CHANNEL ID)
```

It will go to that server

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna send a message every 15 seconds then you can use my code.
language : Python
Requirements : Selenium module

Code :

> ```
> import time
> from random import randint
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
> import os, shutil
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>
> driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
> time.sleep(6)
>
> #--------------- Edit Here -------------------------------------------------------------
>
> # Enter your account details here 
> username = ''
> password = ''
>
> # Copy the URL of channel where you wanna send messages and paste below
> channelURL = "https://discord.com/channels/775349757060186142/77535656021144289331"
>
> #-------------- Edit End ----------------------------------------------------------------
>
> # Initialize and input email
> username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
> username_input.send_keys(username)
>
> # Initialize and input password
> password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
> password_input.send_keys(password)
>
> # Initialize and login
> login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]')
> login_button.click()
> print(">>Login Complete!")
> time.sleep(10)
>
> driver.get(channelURL)
> print(">Opening The Server Link...")
> time.sleep(5)
>
>
> #number of time you wanna change
> x = 80
>
> # Msg Sending
>
> while(i <= x):
>     time.sleep(60*15)
>
>
>     msg_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/main/form/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div')
>
>     msg_input.send_keys("Your msg")
>     msg_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
>     i+=1
>     print(">Number of Messages sent: "+str(i))
> print("Its Done!")
> ```

Comment: I didn't get it :)

Comment: the Xpath is invalid.. I guess its cuz of the Discord update. could  Can you update it as well?